# How can I create a list of possible combination in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I have a python dict as following :

```
test = {"a": value_of_a,"b": value_of_b, "c": value_of_c}
```

Where `value_of_a, value_of_b, value_of_c` are all variable which can take 3 values :

- 1,2 or 3  for `value_of_a`
- "a","b" or "c" for `value_of_b`,
- 45,180,250 for `vaulue_of_c`

I would like to create a list of dicts where each dict contain one combination of these values . for example a dict could be as follow :

```
test1 = {"a" : 2, "b" : "a", "c" : 45 }
test2 = {"a" : 3, "b" : "a", "c" : 45 }
```

and so on...

I don't have any Idea how I can proceed to solve this ?

*NOTE : These value are only to simplify the task, the original task has more keys and values for each, but If I can do it for those this trivial example I can do it for my original task .*

Comment: Do you mean randomly chosen? or every possible combination?

Comment: `for a, b, c in itertools.product(range(1 ,4), 'abc', (45, 180, 250)): print({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using special [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). Please have a look at examples at the bottom of the page - there're some interesting cases.

```
>>> import itertools

>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Enjoy:

```
import itertools


def iterate_values(S):
    keys, values = zip(*S.items())

    for row in itertools.product(*values):
        yield dict(zip(keys, row))


S = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["a", "b", "c"], "c": [45, 180, 250]}

for d in iterate_values(S):
    print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 45, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 45, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 45, 'b': 'c'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 180, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 180, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 180, 'b': 'c'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 250, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 250, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 250, 'b': 'c'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 45, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 45, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 45, 'b': 'c'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 180, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 180, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 180, 'b': 'c'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 250, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 250, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 2, 'c': 250, 'b': 'c'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 45, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 45, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 45, 'b': 'c'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 180, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 180, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 180, 'b': 'c'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 250, 'b': 'a'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 250, 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 3, 'c': 250, 'b': 'c'}
```

I implemented it as a generator, because it saves your memory. If you need an exact list, you may do this:

```
lst = list(iterate_values(S))
```

Comment: Great answer! Just let me write the same code in a more compressed way: `S = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["a", "b", "c"], "c": [45, 180, 250]} \\
keys, values = S.keys(), S.values() \\
value_combs =list(product(*values)) \\ 
all_dict = [ dict(zip(keys, value_comb)) for value_comb in value_combs ]`

Answer (score 1):

Please specify if you want all possible combinations or randomly selected elements from the value lists. If you want every combination, use @Eugene Litsisky's solution. If you're looking for a set of dictionaries with values randomly drawn from the value lists, you can use [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

```
import numpy as np

test1 = {'a': np.random.choice(value_of_a),
         'b': np.random.choice(value_of_b),
         'c': np.random.choice(value_of_c)}
```